# Java code cannot invoke method from scriptengine with new context

Tags: java, scriptengine

I am trying to implement example invoking method from Javascript in Java.

```
private static final String JS = "function doit(p) { list.add(p); return true; }";

public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


    ScriptEngineManager scriptManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = scriptManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();
    context.setBindings(engine.createBindings(), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    Bindings scope = context.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    scope.put("list", list);
    engine.eval(JS, context);

    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
    invocable.invokeFunction("doit", "Hello!!!");

    System.out.println(list.size());
}
}
```

This code throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function doit
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:204)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:383)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
    at testjavascriptinteraction.TestJavaScript.main(TestJavaScript.java:32)
```

#### Version

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: @PEF There is nothing more to see. What more would you need?

Comment: This code is working if I will use initial script context, but it does not with new one for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem, and have found a way how to solve it.

I had a hunch that after casting to `Invocable`, the engines own scripting context is still being used, and not the temporary one you have passed to `eval`.

I can fix this by calling `engine.setContext(...)` with this context before casting to `Invacable`. i.e.:

```
...
scope.put("list", list);
engine.eval(JS, context); // 'context' now contains the 'doit' function.

engine.setContext(context); // <-- Right here
Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine; // Now the Invocable will use 'context'.
invocable.invokeFunction("doit", "Hello!!!"); //Runs fine

System.out.println(list.size());
```

The fact that this works seems to confirm my hunch.

Comment: If you set the engines context, why not just use the engines own/default context?

Comment: @Andreas I was wondering about that too, but I guess you can switch between contexts if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scope` and your `eval()` are both using a custom `ScriptContext`, but your `invokeFunction()` is not. The function is registered with the context, not the engine.

*Option 1:* Don't use a custom context.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

ScriptEngineManager scriptManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = scriptManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

Bindings scope = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
scope.put("list", list);

engine.eval("function doit(p) { list.add(p); return true; }");

Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
invocable.invokeFunction("doit", "Hello!!!");

System.out.println(list); // prints: [Hello!!!]
```

**UPDATE**

*Option 2:* Call registered function directly.

A function get registered with the context as a normal variable with a function value. This means that your `scope` will have a `doit` variable after the `eval()` call.

You will have to use a Nashorn class to call it directly, but it's easy.

```
// same code as above up to eval call
engine.eval("function doit(p) { list.add(p); return true; }", context);

// Instead of invokeFunction(), just get and call function manually
JSObject func = (JSObject)scope.get("doit");
func.call(null, "Hello!!!"); // like a "static" call, no 'this' value

System.out.println(list); // prints: [Hello!!!]
```

Comment: The problem is that I need new context. Thanks.

Comment: @KirillUsov Solved. Engine is left unchanged. Context is used.